# Adding Latin characters to font

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, creative-cloud

So this may be a lot of times answered question but to be honest, I'm still lost. But to the point...

I need to add Latin-extended characters to particular font. I've tried a bunch of SW but all of them are so complex I can't believe it's that difficult. I've managed to find a script for Adobe InDesign that can do that pretty easily, but shame on me, the full version still costs a lot of money.

Is there a way to do this using only apps from Creative Cloud? Since I pay Adobe a lot of money I would suggest there is a way to do that. Maybe in Illustrator?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are no Adobe font editors AFAIK

Comment: There are certainly font editors . . . FontForge is free and Open Source.

Comment: @BillyKerr free editor yes but not free to learn and operate.

Comment: Complicated. Buy a font that already has what you need, it will save you a ton of time.

Comment: @jooja - absolutely!!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do in indesign. But this is very convoluted and requires you to know EVEN more than a font editor, which is why the script author wants some money of you.*

In general it is not possible to do anything font related without a lot of work. Simply because proper kerning is very tedious to do and any font. And fonts are MUCH more complicated than your average vector drawing. Hinting and all such things require a lot of effort.

But yes i do fonts in illustrator, but then teaching you how to do it would still require too much of my and your time. And 2000 lines of custom code, wich is part of the time to teach you.

* if you know how the interals work then you can do fonts in pretty much any system all you need is a text editor really. But given that learning all you need takes >100 hours... Makes a font editor a bargain.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand that it's not a bad thing to want someones money for something that is both useful and works. It's just that this is a one time thing for us at the office, so spending like 300 euros just to edit one font, for which our client will not even pay that much, is not really a good investnment right now. But thanks anyway! The important thing is that it CAN actually be done in Illustrator.

Comment: @Petr yeah i know. The problem is that 300 euros is pretty peanuts, if my somebody in my organisation asked me to do it would cost them 2 000-3 000 for the font, just for covering my salary. If i needed to do a editor i would charge 20 000 +

Comment: @Petr there are free font editors (or even trials of paid ones) that you could use

Comment: @Petr Also it can be done in illustrator with about 2000 lines fo code on top of standard illustrator